# How to count cells with values in another sheet's last column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I want to count cells which are not blank in another sheet's last column.

Now I'm using this formula in sheet1:

```
=COUNT($'Sheet2'.H11:H54).
```

At the end of every month I add 2 columns to sheet2.

How can I change my formula to work when I add extra the columns?

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 2, select the range H11:H54 and give it a name by clicking in the box to the left of the formula bar.  For example, `LastColumn`.

Then, change your formula to `=COUNT (LastColumn)`.

Whenever you add columns to sheet 2, redefine the name `LastColumn` to refer to the new last column.  They way you will not have to change the formula on sheet 1.

Comment: What's the difference of changing the formula or redefining the name every time? The idea of the question is; the formula should always look at the last column of the range, and shouldn't require monthly maintenance.